# Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: $not needs a regex or a document in rails mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Rails app has Moingoid 7.0.5

```
class Example
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :name, type: String
end
```

And when I query `Example.not(name: "xyz").count`, I get this error:

> Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: $not needs a regex or a document (2)
> (on localhost:27017, modern retry, attempt 1) (on localhost:27017,
> modern retry, attempt 1)

Mongoid Documentation does say that we can use *`not`* operator this way as well. I do get expected results for `Example.where(:name.ne => "xyz").count`.

Is there something in configuration that leads to this?

Comment: Where did you find this usage in the documentation?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-queries/#logical-operations.   in codesection under not with conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The published documentation indicates which version it applies to (upper left corner). Current Mongoid release is 7.2, thus https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-queries/#logical-operations shows that it applies to 7.2. You can select the version you are using from the dropdown.

The `not` behavior you are asking about is working the way it is described in current documentation from Mongoid 7.1. Previous versions of Mongoid, as you found out, don't work as currently described.